# If $f_{n} \in L^{\infty}$, $ \int_{0}^{1}f_{n_{k}}(x)g(x)dx \rightarrow \int_{0}^{1}f(x)g(x)dx$ for every $g \in L^1$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Supposet that $\{f_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty} \in L^{\infty}$. Is the following statement always true?

> There is a subsequence $\{n_{k}\}$ and a function $f \in L^{\infty}$ such that
>   $$ \int_{0}^{1}f_{n_{k}}(x)g(x)dx \rightarrow \int_{0}^{1}f(x)g(x)dx$$
>   for every $g \in L^1$

Comment: If $(f_n)$ has a bounded subsequence, yes for a separable $L_1$ space. In this case, for $X=L_1$, $B(X^*)$ is weak* metrizable and the result follows from this and Alaoglu's Theorem.

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. I know that $\int f_{n_{k}}gdx$ converges to some $l(g) \in (L^{1})^{*}$ by Alaoglu's theorem. But it doesn't guarantee that $l(g)=\int fgdx$.

Comment: If $(f_n)$ is bounded, by Alaoglu and the metrizability of $B(L_1^*)$, there is a subsequence $(f_{n_k})$ of $(f_n)$ that is weak* convergent. So, by definition, there is an $f\in L_\infty$ such that $\lim\limits_{k\rightarrow\infty}\int f_{n_k} g=\int fg$ for all $g\in L_1$. Am I missing something?

Comment: Oh my god. I mistake $(L^1)^{*}$ for $(L^{\infty})^{*}$. Thanks!